# How to map Menu key ("Application key") to Escape key in vim?

Tags: vim, menu, dictionary, escaping, key

I think that using Menu key to quit vim's insert mode would be a great thing. It would be also nice to use Super key for that, but I'm not sure if it possible since Super key is a modifier.

Anyway, I couldn't find anything related to this. Looking for your help and thanks in advance!

Comment: Read the 42 pdf in this url http://zmievski.org/talks/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's any way you can configure Vim to pay attention to the Menu key as such,
but depending on your system there are various ways to turn the Menu key into an Escape key.

If you're using X11 on Linux:

- The command `xmodmap -e 'keycode 135 = Escape'` will turn your Menu key into an Escape key for the current session, but is not permanent.  To make it permanent under Gnome, you might try adding it under System → Preferences → Startup Applications.
- The `xkeycaps` program will give you a GUI for similar remappings.

For more information:

http://46dogs.blogspot.com/2008/05/remap-keys-in-ubuntu-804-hardy-heron.html

http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-106209.html

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a way to map it in gVim yet, but I was able to successfully map the Menu key in a `urxvt`+`screen`+`vim` stack by the following method:

1. In a terminal, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> and press <kbd>Menu</kbd>. This is mapped to the `quoted-insert` function in Zsh and in Readline-based tools like Bash.
2. It will generate an escape sequence like `^[[29~` at the prompt. (The initial `^[` must be translated to `<Esc>` for use in `.vimrc`.)
3. Open up `.vimrc` and add a line like this:

```
imap <Esc>[29~ <Esc>
```

(or `imap <Esc>[29~ <Esc><Esc>` if you don't want it to wait for further input like the Escape key does.)

Note that not all keys return something usable from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>. This is a limitation of terminal emulators and can be remedied by remapping the key. You may be able to do that at the level of the terminal emulator rather than for all X apps.

For example, for `urxvt`, I had to add the following lines to `~/.Xresources` and run `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources` to apply them:

```
! Unbreak zsh keys in URxvt
URxvt*keysym.Home: \033[1~
URxvt*keysym.End: \033[4~
```

(`\033` is `<Esc>` in `~/.Xresources` syntax.)

Answer (score 0):

Just try using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> instead of binding another key. This combination is a standard one in vim, btw.

This is even easier when having rebound <kbd>capslock</kbd> into an additional <kbd>ctrl</kbd>.