# How do I switch between command and insert mode in Vim?

Tags: vim, insert, command

I just started using Vim as an IDE. I was using it as a test editor for a while now, so I didn't have to go to command mode very often. But, since I program in Java, I have to go to command mode to make the file, compile/run it... etc.

The problem is: I need a good way to switch between the two modes.

I looked online and it says that the `<Esc>` key is supposed to do that, but that doesn't work for me (maybe it's not for gVim? I don't know why.)

I have to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> every time to go to command mode; the escape key works from that mode... it brings me back to insert mode. But is there a better, or easier, way of switching between command mode and insert mode?

Comment: Esc is definitely the right key to finish an insert.  An insert can be started in various ways.  Lowercase i to start inserting at your cursor, uppercase I to start inserting at the beginning of the line, etc.

Comment: Starting from an empty file, the following characters should give you a file with the word "hello" in it:  `ihello<ESC>:w hello.txt<ENTER>`

Comment: `ctrl-[` works as a substitute for Esc on many keyboards.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Looks like your Vim is launched in *easy mode*. See `:help easy`.

This happens when Vim is invoked with the `-y` argument or as `evim`, or maybe you have a `:set insertmode` somewhere in your `.vimrc` configuration. Find the source and disable it; temporarily this can be also done via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> `:set noim` <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: I think that was it. I had insert-mode enabled in my file. After I removed it, the escape-key works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: this is easy mode!?

Comment: Vim easy mode, now that's an oxymoron. Is that where it's possible to exit vim?

Comment: @Davos that's the mode where it is started in insert mode, so ironically it's a mode where it's not possible to exit vim :p
"normal mode" is way easier just alt+:,x XD

Answer (score 122):

Pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> quits from insert mode to normal mode, where you can press <kbd>:</kbd> to type in a command.
Press <kbd>i</kbd> again to back to insert mode, and you are good to go.

I'm not a Vim guru, so someone else can be more experienced and give you other options.

Comment: For most of us, but the accepted answer had the answer to the specific problem.

Answer (score 33):

This has been mentioned in [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4416543/3653165), but <kbd>ctrl + [</kbd> is an equivalent to <kbd>ESC</kbd> on all keyboards.

Comment: I never knew that, useful when escape key is not supported

Comment: Wow, thanks for that information!
Tmux copying keystroke sequence now makes much more sense.

Answer (score 6):

Coming from emacs I've found that I like `ctrl +` keys to do stuff, and in vim I've found that both `[ctrl + C]` and `[alt + backspace]` will enter Normal mode from insert mode. You might try and see if any of those works out for you.

Comment: Saved my life on a cpanel terminal emulator, where ESC is not working. thx ;)

Answer (score 5):

Using `jj`

In my case, the .vimrc (or in gVim it is in `_vimrc`) setting below.

```
inoremap jj <Esc>   """ jj key is <Esc> setting
```

Comment: This is a common remapping. I find it has a slight delay as it waits for additional character input. Alternatively, remap your capslock key to esc using something like KeyRemap4MacBook on a Macbook: https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook

Comment: i found it easier to remap tab to esc :3

Answer (score 5):

For me, the problem was that I was in [recording mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#q). To exit from recording mode press <kbd>q</kbd>. Then <kbd>Esc</kbd> worked as expected for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Alt+H,J,K,L to move cursor in insert mode.

Comment: No, you can't. That is probably a remap of your configuration.

Comment: @SaulAxelMartinezOrtiz yes you can, tho technically it exits normal mode after which you can move around in normal mode :p

Comment: just to add same way you can do Alt+/ Alt+? Alt+: and so on

Comment: @SaulAxelMartinezOrtiz something might catch your input with Alt key thus making it not working in vim

Answer (score 0):

There is also one more solution for that kind of problem, which is rather rare, I think, and you may experience it, if you are using vim on OS X Sierra. Actually, it's a problem with Esc button — not with vim. For example, I wasnt able to exit fullscreen video on youtube using Esc, but I lived with that for a few months until I had experienced the same problem with vim.

I found [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/252374) solution. If you are lazy enough to follow external link, switching off Siri and killing the process in Activity Monitor helped.